# Sending Firebase notifications one after another

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending Firebase notificatiosn from a PHP script.

This is the function I am using:

```
 function enviar_push($token,$titulo,$subtitulo){

            define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAv.....');
            $msg = array
                  (
                'body'  => $subtitulo,
                'title' => $titulo,
                'subtitle'  => 'test test test'

                  );
            $fields = array
                    (
                        'to'        => $token,
                        'notification'  => $msg
                    );


            $headers = array
                    (
                        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );
            #Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                $result = curl_exec($ch );

                curl_close( $ch );
        }
```

If I call the function one time from the script, it works fine. But I need to send it twice with different title and subtitle.

To call the function, I am using the following code:

```
$token_cliente = get_token_cliente( $_POST['siete']);

                    $titulo = "UPICK ";
                    $subtitulo = "PENDIENTE DESIGNACION CHOFER";

                    enviar_push($token_cliente,$titulo,$subtitulo);
```

But I need to send two notifications. If I put a second call after, then only the second notification is sent.

```
$token_cliente = get_token_cliente( $_POST['siete']);

                    $titulo = "UPICK ";
                    $subtitulo = "PENDIENTE DESIGNACION CHOFER";

                    enviar_push($token_cliente,$titulo,$subtitulo);
$token_cliente = get_token_cliente( $_POST['ocho']);

                    $titulo = "UPICK 8";
                    $subtitulo = "PENDIENTE DESIGNACION CHOFER 8";

                    enviar_push($token_cliente,$titulo,$subtitulo);
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Move `define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAv.....');` outside the function

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, done, but it does not solve my issue. Thank you.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, yes. The mobile phone only receives the second notification

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, sorry ...the function is enviar_push()

Comment: Ok, the code looks fine, add [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and `print_r($result)` to see if the issue is with the API, it may respond with something useful.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, both notifications receivers could be the same device

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, the response is from both notifications and the result is always SUCCESS. I guess the device is getting both notifications and overlaps the first with the second, could that be possible?

Comment: im not sure, but you could test that by putting a `sleep(5)` in between the calls.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, I have tried it before, but the response freezes the app then

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, confirmed, I have been watching the notifications implementing the sleep (5) method and the first appears fine, and then the second overlaps the first one....

Comment: np, ive been looking for a limit but cant find any, so if your getting success, that must be the issue (overlapping).

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, yes. Thank you again.

Comment: Checking out message [types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages), notifications are always collapsible. And according to the documentation "A collapsible message is a message that may be replaced by a new message if it has yet to be delivered to the device." Therefore, the new message will always replace the old. Depending on the needs of your app, you could use a data message and handle it client-side, which would give you the option to make the messages non-collapsible.